how to create custom video embed ratios in bootstrap?
Update:
I've managed to embed a non-standard bootstrap video size (of proportion: 4x5)... however, unlike standard bootstrap embeds it doesn't seem to obey a MAX HEIGHT anywhere i put it - on the iframe, or divs around it.
(to see the issue, view the page, and view full size - the tall phone video shows the issue... is way too tall)
any ideas how to fix, or ways around it?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multiple Responsive Slideshows</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: violet;
      margin: 10px; /* Reset margin to 0 */
      padding: 0; /* Reset padding to 0 */
    }

    .container {
      background-color: green;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; }

    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #b9dbe5;
      display: flex; /* Use flexbox layout */
      justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
      align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    }

    .carousel-item {
      text-align: center; /* Center images horizontally */
    }

    .slideshow-container img, 
    .slideshow-container iframe {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }

    /* Show arrows only on hover */
    .slideshow-container:hover .prev, 
    .slideshow-container:hover .next {
      display: block;
    }

    .prev, .next {
      display: none;
      cursor: default; /* Change cursor to default */
      z-index: 1000;
      color: silver;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: auto;
      padding: 16px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
    }

    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
      color: silver; /* Change color on hover */
    }

    .prev {
      left: 0;
    }

    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    .prev.disabled, .next.disabled {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
      
   /* //////// Media query ////////  */
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    body {
        background-color: goldenrod;
        
 /* Videos and can be full width on mobile */
      }
         .carousel-item img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }

      .carousel-item iframe {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
      }
        .vidbox {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        max-height: 100% !important;
      }
    }

 /* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video */
    .embed-responsive-4by5 {
      padding-bottom: 125%; /* 5/4 aspect ratio */
    }
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 1000px">
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="slideshow-container carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      
    <!-- Image Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1200x600/?kitten" style="padding: 30px;">   
        </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x500/?shark" style="max-height: 150px;">
      </div>
   
                  <!-- Video Slide -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
    <div id="phone" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by5" style="max-height: 80vh;">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/912417077?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="padding: 0px"></iframe>
     </div>
    </div>
        
    
              <!-- Video Slide -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
    <div id="nochill" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="max-width: 800px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/143374377?h=760ef66606&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="padding: 0px;"></iframe>
      </div>    
    </div>
        
          <!-- Video Slide -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
    <div id="squarevid" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1" style="max-height: 80vh;">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/21480736?h=41e5c84cdf&color=183eb1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="padding: 0px"></iframe>
      </div>    
    </div>
        
        
    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <a class="prev" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navigation Click anywhere to navigate -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-inner').on('click', function(e) {
      if (e.pageX < $(this).width() / 2) {
        $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('prev');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.carousel').carousel('next');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>



<!-- Video Slide -->
  <div class="carousel-item">
<div id="phone" class="vidbox embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by5" style="max-height: 80vh;">

and adding this CSS:
/* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video */
.embed-responsive-4by5 {
  padding-bottom: 125%; /* 5/4 aspect ratio */
}
  

Docs I've bene referring to  re: embeds, and custom ratios:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/#custom-ratios
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/embed/


Behind the scenes, Bootstrap uses the following formula:
.embed-responsive-XbyY {
  padding-top: 100% * Y / X;
}

Which means you can add your own class to your custom CSS, if you don't feel comfortable recompiling Bootstrap or overriding its variables:
.embed-responsive-4by5 {
  padding-top: 125%;
}


yes! thank you.
that is a similar solve to what i ended up using. the trouble i'm having now is that although it now scales correctly now, just like the other standard embeds - it doesnt obey a MAX HEIGHT if i add it to the video iframe, or the divs that it's in.
do you have any idea how to fix that? it seems to ignore any requests for max height wherever you place it. e.g. if i wanted to the max height of this video to be 600px.

First of all, that's a different question. Secondly, if you want the video to have a max-height, since you know its ratio you can wrap it into a centered div with  max-width of  max-height * .8. In short, for a video max-height: 800px  you give the wrapper max-width: 640px. It might work by applying the max-width on the video itself. If it doesn't, use the wrapper.

I just saw you want a max-height of 600px. max-width: 480px should achieve just that. If you want a full explanation, you'll need to ask it as a separate question. In short, Bootstrap's aspect-ratio uses a legacy method (where the video is absolutely positioned in an empty container who's height is defined by percentage, which is actually a percentage of the width, not of the height). It's a bit of a hack, but works cross-browser. Technically, the content height of the container is 0. So you can only control its height  through its width, which determines the top-padding.

this worked, thank you so much (using ::before in the css) as on another thread helped ensure that it worked every time.

As in the documents, you should recompile to have a custom aspect ratio. This is done by overriding the variable in file _variables.scss:
$embed-responsive-aspect-ratios: (
  (21 9),
  (16 9),
  (4 3),
  (1 1)
) !default;

Instead of modifying the source files, your main.scss should look like this:
// main.scss

$embed-responsive-aspect-ratios: (
  (21 9),
  (16 9),
  (4 3),
  (4 5),
  (1 1)
);

import 'bootstrap/_bootstrap.scss';

// rest of your styles...
// now should have: 
.embed-responsive-4by5 {
  // ...
}



Could you clarify what you mean by "as in the documents"?.  If the above method to add a custom custom ratio to Bootstrap is documented in their official documentation, consider linking the resource in your answer. Please note this question is specific for v4.x.

hello there, thank you for the responses. i managed to find a fix by adding a new embed-responsive-4by5 to the div, then defining it in the CSS:
/* Custom aspect ratio for 4x5 video /
.embed-responsive-4by5 {
padding-bottom: 125%; / 5/4 aspect ratio */
}
it works great and scales correctly - but the problem i'm having now is that i'm unable to set a max height. any ideas how to fix?
